# Wordpress 5+ Automatic link all gallery images to media file

Tags: wordpress, gallery, block, wordpress-gutenberg

Please guys i really need your help, I'm stuck with that!

[image]

Before WP 5 I was linked all gallery images to "file" automatically by using this filter below.

```
add_filter( 'shortcode_atts_gallery',
    function( $out ){
        $out['link'] = 'file'; 
        return $out;
    }
);
```

But after WP 5 how can i make it to work again? I really need to Link all gallery images to " media file " automatically!